# Displaying from my database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I'm new to rails and I'm working on a project where I'm having an issue. I'm trying to display all the gyms that have the same zipcode. When I tried the code below, it only displays 1 and not the other ones. How can display all the gym that have the same zip code?

**controller**

```
def gym
  @fitness = Fitness.find_by(zip_code: params[:zip_code])
end
```

**gym.html.erb**

```
<%= @fitness.name %>
```

Comment: Here's a piece of advice for any developer in general: whatever framework, tool or library you're working with, there's a good chance it has [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find_by). Don't be lazy and ask for help the moment you run into trouble. Do some research. Find the documentation. Read it. Apply what you learn. If you're the type who won't help yourself, you shouldn't expect to last long in this industry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing this to yourself. By [definition](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find_by), #find_by only returns a single record, or nil. You probably want [#where](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#hash-conditions) instead:

```
Fitness.where(zip_code: params[:zip_code])
```

If that still doesn't work, check both your table data and the content of your params hash to make sure you're creating a valid query.

Answer (score 1):

```
def gyms
  @fitness = Fitness.where("zip_code = ?", params[:zip_code])
end
```

Comment: Not sure why you flipped this from the concise hash notation to the long-form string with placeholder version. It should be `where(zip_code: params[:zip_code])` but this is otherwise correct.